# BootJar + MavenJar. Artifact wasn't produced by this build

Tags: gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, maven-publish

I have a sample project with the following hierearhy:

```
Sample (root)
   -- model (simple jar)
   -- api   (springboot jar)
```

I want to publish both generated jars: plain jar & bootJar to my localRepository.

```
gradlew clean build -xTest publishToMavenLocal
```

However, the following error occures:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':api:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'mavenLocal'
   > Artifact api.jar wasn't produced by this build.
```

The root build.gradle is a follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.2.5.RELEASE" apply false
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}
group 'sample'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
ext {
    artifactVersion = version
    springBootVersion = "2.2.5.RELEASE"
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
    apply plugin: "maven-publish"

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
                groupId project.group
                artifactId project.name
                version project.version

                from components.java
            }
        }
    }
}
```

api build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    compile project(":model")
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
}

bootJar {
}
```

Adding bootJava task to api build.gradle allowes to publish the bootJar directly from api module, but the root publish task remains broken.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        bootJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bootJar
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried almost every solution from docs & google, but none seem to work.
Can anyone explain, what is misconfigured?

Gradle version: 6.3

Comment: Works fine with Gradle 5.3. :-(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As stated by gradle documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html):

> Starting from Gradle 6.2, Gradle performs a sanity check before uploading, to make sure you don’t upload stale files (files produced by another build). This introduces a problem with Spring Boot applications which are uploaded using the components.java component

More explanation is available in the link above.
They propose the following workaround that I personally tried and worked for me :

**configure the outgoing configurations**

```
configurations {
       [apiElements, runtimeElements].each {
           it.outgoing.artifacts.removeIf { it.buildDependencies.getDependencies(null).contains(jar) }
           it.outgoing.artifact(bootJar)
       }
    }
```

here after the configuration from my build.gradle:

```
....
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
...

configurations {
    [apiElements, runtimeElements].each {
        it.outgoing.artifacts.removeIf { it.buildDependencies.getDependencies(null).contains(jar) }
        it.outgoing.artifact(bootJar)
    }
    ....
}


publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            groupId groupId
            artifactId artifactId
            version version
            from components.java
            versionMapping {
                usage('java-api') {
                    fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                }
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url azureRepoUrl
            name azureRepoName
            credentials {
                username azureRepoUserName
                password azureRepoAccessToken
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share extra information? Where is it placed? I'm receiving  Cannot convert the provided notation to an object of type ConfigurablePublishArtifact

Comment: Note: in multimodule project 'configurations' block  should be in the module with bootjar task

Comment: None of the solution works for bootWar task. Any idea?

Comment: The additional lines in `configurations {}` is what worked for me, Gradle v6.5 in my case.

Answer (score 13):

**Excerpt [from](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#publishing_spring_boot_applications)**

Starting from Gradle **6.2**, the main **`jar`** task is disabled by the Spring Boot application, and the `component` expects it to be present. Because the **`bootJar`** task uses the same file as the main **`jar`** task by default, previous releases of Gradle would either:

- publish a stale `bootJar` artifact
- or fail if the bootJar task hasn’t been called previously

To simple workaround would be configuring the outgoing configurations. For multi-module Gradle project, place the below configuration in the service module(spring boot module).

```
dependencies {
          .....
}

configurations {
    [apiElements, runtimeElements].each {
        it.outgoing.artifacts.removeIf {
            it.buildDependencies.getDependencies(null).contains(jar)
        }
        it.outgoing.artifact(bootJar)
    }
}
```

Note: There is no need for changing anything with `artifactory` task if it was configured correctly. This working solution has been tested with **`Gradle 6.4.1`**.

**Don't try** the alternate suggestion that they provided, because `classifier` attribute is deprecated in recent versions, also altering the `bootJar` task with custom configuration would result in improper **uber** jar construction, and if you extract the generated jar distributive, you could find the missing **`BOOT-INF`** directory and necessary  `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` values.

```
jar {
   enabled = true
}

bootJar {
   classifier = 'application'
}
```

**Update:**

From **`Spring Boot 2.5.0`**, `jar` task generates an additional jar archive which ends with `-plain.jar`. It may break someone's build if they have used some patterns like `*.jar` to copy the build archive, hence, to restrict the additional jar creation, the following `jar` task configuration code snippet should be used.

```
jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

Comment: What are `apiElements` and `runtimeElements` in `[apiElements, runtimeElements].each` above?

Answer (score 12):

I could get this worked by just adding `artifact bootJar` in the publishing task as shown below and with out adding any configurations as suggested in the gradle documentation. I believe this could be working same as their first workaround in the documentation. Tested with gradle `6.5.1`

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bootJar
            artifact sourceJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
        }
    }
}

project.tasks.publish.dependsOn bootJar
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the 'Gradle' documentation under,

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#publishing_spring_boot_applications

Just add the following to the `build.gradle` file

```
jar {
   enabled = true
}

bootJar {
   classifier = 'application'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gradle kotlin dsl add the equivalent in your build.gradle. It worked for me

```
 configurations {
    val elements = listOf(apiElements, runtimeElements)
    elements.forEach { element ->
        element.get().outgoing.artifacts.removeIf { it -> it.buildDependencies.getDependencies(null).contains(tasks.jar.get())}
        element.get().outgoing.artifact(tasks.bootJar.get())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Spring Boot 2.5.0+, this configurations works for publishing the embedded jar, its sources and javadoc:

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java-library'
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}

java {
    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        publication(MavenPublication) {
            artifact bootJar
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```