# Gradle maven publish plugin fails in a multi-module project with error "Artifact wasn't produced by this build"

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi-module project which supports *maven* and *gradle* builds hence it contains `pom.xml` files along side with `build.gradle`. I'm working on a demo and I would like to show how to build and deploy to nexus the same project using either *gradle* or *maven*. That's why I have two different build systems in case you wonder why.

You may see the project structure below.

[image: project structure]

You may look into the code [here](https://github.com/eljaiek/machinery-config/tree/dev-gradle-publish-error).

I've configured the *gradle* *maven-publish* plugin in order to publish all modules to my local nexus repository however when I run `gradle publish` I hit this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven'
   > Artifact machinery-config-0.0.1.jar wasn't produced by this build.
```

The issue is related with having the `publishing` section within `$rootDir/build.gradle`.

It's confusing *maven-publish* somehow which is trying to publish an artifact that doesn't exist `machinery-config-0.0.1.jar`, `machinery-config` is the name of the `rootProject`.

One workaround could be to remove the `publishing` section from the `rootProject` and duplicate it in the sub-projects. I don't like that approach cuz I will end up with a lot of duplicated code.

Could you point me out a better way to use *maven-publish* within a multi-module project ?

Comment: Why are you using two different build systems in the same project? As far as I can tell, they are the same. I would take a look at whatever the Spring Boot team did. Before their migration to Gradle, their Gradle plugin was built using Gradle, but the rest of the project was Maven. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/2.2.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Comment: Because I'm working on a presentation and I would like to show how to build the same project using maven or gradle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BootJar + MavenJar. Artifact wasn't produced by this build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197984/bootjar-mavenjar-artifact-wasnt-produced-by-this-build)

Comment: No, It doesn't cuz `bootJar` is disabled. I think  the issue is not related with the maven build, will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I realized that I had two issues:

1. `publishing` section was outside of `subprojects` section, then **gradle** tried to deploy an artifact using `rootProject.name` ignoring the included modules.
2. `group` & `version` properties were outside `subprojects` therefore deployed artifacts had `undefined` as version number, e.g `machinery-config-core-undefined.jar`

In order to fix issue number two I had moved `group` & `version` into `subprojects` section.

My build also produces a [BOM](https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency/) artifact hence I need two publications `from components.java` and `from components.javaPlatform`, so I wrote this script `gradle/ext/publish-common.gradle` which exports two functions I will use later on both publications to keep code duplication [at bay](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+bay).

```
def pom(it) {
    it.licenses {
        license {
            name = 'The Apache License, Version 2.0'
            url = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
        }
    }

    it.developers {
        developer {
            id = 'eljaiek'
            name = 'Eduardo Eljaiek'
            email = 'eduardo.eljaiek@gmail.com'
        }
    }

    it.scm {
        connection = 'scm:git:git://github.com/eljaiek/machinery-config.git'
        developerConnection = 'scm:git:git@github.com:eljaiek/machinery-config.git'
        url = 'https://github.com/eljaiek/machinery-config'
    }
}

def nexusRepository(it) {
    it.url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? project.nexusSnapshotsUrl : project.nexusReleasesUrl
    it.credentials {
        username project.nexusUser
        password project.nexusPasswd
    }
}

ext {
    pom = this.&pom
    nexusRepository = this.&nexusRepository
}
```

I had added `from components.javaPlatform` publication into `machinery-config-dependencies/build.gradle` in order to deploy the **BOM** artifact

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/ext/publish-common.gradle"


publishing {
    publications {
        mavenBom(MavenPublication) {
            from components.javaPlatform

            pom { x -> pom(x)}
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven { x -> nexusRepository(x) }
    }
}
```

`apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/ext/publish-common.gradle"` will aplly the script I wrote, this is required in order to import `pom()` and `nexusRepository()` functions into my build script.

To deploy `from components.java` artifacts I had added a `publishing` section in `subprojects` under `if (it.name != 'machinery-config-dependencies')` statement into `$rootDir/build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'ru.vyarus.pom'
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/ext/publish-common.gradle"

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
                pom { x -> pom(x)}
            }
        }

        repositories {
           maven { x -> nexusRepository(x) }
        }
}
```

I had used [Gradle POM plugin](https://github.com/xvik/gradle-pom-plugin#manual-pom-modification) instead of `maven-publish`. It provides maven's dependencies declaration simplicity and implicitly applies **maven-publish** plugin.

See the code [here](https://github.com/eljaiek/machinery-config/tree/master)

References

[Extract common methods from Gradle build script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715137/extract-common-methods-from-gradle-build-script)

[The Java Platform Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html)