# Spring Boot 2.5.0 generates plain.jar file. Can I remove it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

After the Spring Boot 2.5.0 update, it generates the `myprogram-0.0.1-plain.jar` file alongside the usual `myprogram-0.0.1.jar`. Can I disallow gradle to generate the `*.plain.jar` file? I use Gradle 7.0.2.

What I get:

```
build/
  libs/
    myprogram-0.0.1.jar
    myprogram-0.0.1-plain.jar
```

What I want:

```
build/
  libs/
    myprogram-0.0.1.jar
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: It helps to read [the spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives): you can disable it if you don't need it.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Yep, thanks. I didn't expect this breaking change. The CI server expected only one file in libs.

Comment: refer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62645933/3303074)

Comment: commenting out the version line `//version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"` and using `war {
   archiveClassifier.set("")
}`  in build.gradle.kts file worked for me (wanted to rename war file in my case). It changed war file name from demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.war to demo.war

Comment: Same problem here. The second jair crashed or build pipelines.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

It was a change in Spring Boot 2.5.0.

As @ThomasKläger pointed out: You can set it in the `build.gradle` configuration.

build.gradle

```
jar {
    enabled = false
}
```

For Kotlin devs:

```
tasks.getByName<Jar>("jar") {
    enabled = false
}
```

Alternatively, you can run the `bootJar` task. It produces only the default runnable jar.

Comment: thanks for the Kotlin example. `tasks.jar { enabled = false }` worked for me; not sure if there's a difference.

Comment: With `jar {enabled = false }` it generates no jar at all (not only with `plain` postfix). How this can be an accepted answer?

Comment: @srzhio strangely enough, this disables only the .plain jar, and not the full jar.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives

Comment: @Innokenty, yep, that is what the documentation state, but only `bootJar.enabled = true; jar.enabled = false` worked for me

Comment: Just tested with a brand new project from start.spring.io with Spring Boot 2.6.5 and adding `jar.enabled = false` and I can confirm that the boot jar is still generated when running `./gradlew build`. The `bootJar.enabled = true` part is not required.

Comment: I'm using Spring boot 2.6 and didn't had this problem until someone switched from Gradle 7 to 8.

Answer (score 42):

Try use follow setting:

```
jar {
   enabled = true
   archiveClassifier = '' //use empty string
}
```

Because `org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.JavaPluginAction.java`

```
private void classifyJarTask(Project project) {
    project.getTasks().named(JavaPlugin.JAR_TASK_NAME, Jar.class)
            .configure((task) -> task.getArchiveClassifier().convention("plain"));
}
```

From `spring-boot-gradle-plugin` sources file:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.5.0/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.5.0-sources.jar

See:

- https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveClassifier

Comment: I needed this because I have the shared library across other projects and I use the spring boot plugin there too. So I cannot set up bootJar enabled to false.

Comment: commenting out the version line `//version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"` and using just `war {
   archiveClassifier.set("")
}`  in build.gradle.kts file worked for me (wanted to rename war file in my case). It changed war file name from demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain.war to demo.war

Comment: if bootjar is true, you want jar enabled false

Answer (score 13):

This gradle config will produce `myprogram-0.0.1.jar` instead of `myprogram-0.0.1-plain.jar`

In your `build.gradle.kts`

```
// Build executable jar
tasks.jar {
    enabled = true
    // Remove `plain` postfix from jar file name
    archiveClassifier.set("")
}
```

Comment: @Ocase you saved me here... Wow... Just migrated an entire app with automated docker builds to use the jars (UnmazedBoot) and I couldn't expect 2 jars LOL

Comment: After using this, I got no manifest to it :( no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/microadmin-service-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar... So, my solution to bypass this was to run `"gradle bootJar"`

Comment: @MarcellodeSales this was my issue too. When running `docker build` I ended up with `When using ADD with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /` when upgrading to Sprint Boot 2.

Answer (score 5):

Tested solution. I was facing the same issue: just add below in your gradle

```
jar{
    archiveClassifier=''
    enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `build` gradle task you could use `bootJar`. That will only build the bootable jar.

Keep in mind that `bootJar` won't run your tests before building.

Comment: Damn, this would have been a nice solution if I wasn't using a common Jenkins build script that will screw up other repos.

Comment: That's actually not true, at least in my case: the bootJar task in my Kotlin project causes creation the both just xxx.jar and the xxx-plain.jar.

Comment: Worked for me.  Am wondering if @PavelPraulov had some other option which forced the "build" to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using springboot,  you can disable generation of  **--plain.jar by adding below code to your gradle file.

```
jar {
    // disable generation of **--plain.jar
    enabled = false
    archiveFileName = bootJar.archiveFileName
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem today！

above springboot 2.5, use jar or war build project will append plain text to the name of target file

```
task.getArchiveClassifier().convention("plain")
```

so you can define this to resolve this problem

```
jar {
    classifier = ''
}
```

yeah, you can see that the author tell you how to config it in this url https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/ebdb046ca93684b45691e689b6a23562dd636b61#diff-5efe17833c4d5e21d01178734dea8859dc1669199669101a36448ed696413820.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content](/help/referencing).