# Gradle publishing to Maven adds a suffix that does not seem to work from Maven POM dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, repository, artifact, maven-publish

When I publish to a local maven repository from a Gradle project, I find that the main JAR file has a `-plain` suffix.

```
pdffer/pdffer-template/1.0-SNAPSHOT 
➜ ll
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 fedmest  staff   918B Sep  1 16:39 maven-metadata-local.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 fedmest  staff   3.8K Sep  1 16:39 pdffer-template-1.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 fedmest  staff   1.9K Sep  1 16:39 pdffer-template-1.0-SNAPSHOT.module
-rw-r--r--  1 fedmest  staff   1.7K Sep  1 16:39 pdffer-template-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

When I include this library as a Maven dependency from a POM file, it cannot find it - it only works if I rename the main JAR to exclude the -plain suffix. Can I get Gradle to generate the JAR without the suffix? Any idea why the suffix appears, please?

Comment: To get the artifact `-plain` you have to define a classifier `<classifier>plain</classifier>` in your dependency... The question is why is it generated with a classifier....

Comment: Good question, I have no idea where it comes from... I have not consciously configured that in my gradle.build

Comment: I have noticed that not all my projects have this issue. The ones that do are using the following plugins: 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3' and 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'. Could they be applying this change? Would anybody know how to undo it?

Comment: @fedmest, Im running into same thing.. by any chance did you get to know the root cause or solution?

Answer (score 3):

To disable 'plain', follow the springboot documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.and-plain-archives

```
jar {
    classifier = ''
}
```

I also found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752182/11723872