# After upgrading to gradle 7.x generating two war files

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, war

After upgrading from gradle 5.x to 7.x, two war files generating.

Below are the 2 war file names

```
test-app-1.0.0.war
test-app-1.0.0-plain.war
```

below is gradle plugin and task used:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
}

bootWar {
    launchScript()
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version':  archiveVersion
    }
}
```

I want to generate only `test-app-1.0.0.war`. How to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you don’t apply the `war` plugin?

Comment: compile time error ```Could not find method bootWar() for arguments [] on root project 'test-app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.```

Comment: That’s weird. Can you create a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You should apply the Spring Boot plugin not the war plugin.

Comment: addding ```war {
    enabled = false
}``` and ```bootWar {
    enabled = true
    launchScript()
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version':  archiveVersion
    }
}``` generating without plain war.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the reference [plain jar - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663728/spring-boot-2-5-0-generates-plain-jar-file-can-i-remove-it):

Changed **build.gradle** like below

```
war {
    enabled = false
}

bootWar {
    enabled = true
    launchScript()
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version':  archiveVersion
    }
}
```

Now it's generating only `test-app-1.0.0.war`