# Spring Boot project searching plain jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am upgrading current system to spring boot 2.5.2 . I have custom spring boot starter which I installed to my local maven repository. But its generating plain jar. I installed plain jar but the project I am gonna use this starter looking for normal jar. When I disable plain jar and install normal jar , its looking plain jar. Is there any way to install both or is there any other way to look only plain jar or normal jar.

Java version is 11, Gradle version is 6.8.3, spring boot version is 2.5.2 , spring boot dependency management version is 1.0.8

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: I have a custom spring boot starter which I am using in different project. Before I upgraded spring boot and java version everything was working. I updated spring version to 2.5.2 and it started generate plain-jar. In this link there is another question related plain jar , you can check .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67663728/spring-boot-2-5-0-generates-plain-jar-file-can-i-remove-it . The project I am using that starter is looking plain-jar. But when I install related plain jar its looking normal jar. Probably I need some configuration but I couldn't find any documentation or something.

Answer (score 1):

In the custom starter one of the module added as a "api project" when I change that to "compile project" in build.gradle it worked. Because of "api project" when it generating jar and pom file it was adding classifier as a "plain" and it was searching plain-jar. After change it, everything worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

sorry , I can't comment. I can't understand your mean.

depend on your message , I know you have write a starter that install to local maven, maybe like `mvn install` , but I don't know what is plain jar, what is normal jar.